Save UIMenuElement in UserDefault and remove before killing the application
I want to save and fetch UIMenuElement state in userdefaults. I have written the following code.  Is it the right way to save. Or the code can be improved?
private func addMenuControlForSubtitles() {
        let actionState: UIMenuElement.State = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "captionState") as! UIMenuElement.State
        let onAction = UIAction(title: Constants.Playback.subtitlesOnTitle, state: actionState) { [weak self] action in
            self?.subtitlesLabel.isHidden = false
            action.state = .on
            UserDefaults.standard.set(action.state, forKey: "captionState")
        }
        
        let offAction = UIAction(title: Constants.Playback.subtitlesOffTitle, state: actionState) { [weak self] action in
            self?.subtitlesLabel.isHidden = true
            action.state = .off
            UserDefaults.standard.set(action.state, forKey: "captionState")
            
        }

        /// Create the submenu.
        let submenu = UIMenu(title: Constants.Playback.subtitlesMenuTitle,
                             options: [.displayInline, .singleSelection],
                             children: [onAction, offAction])

        let captions = UIImage(systemName: "captions.bubble")
        subtitlesMenu = UIMenu(title: Constants.Playback.productCardMenuTitle, image: captions, children: [submenu])
        /// set initial state to hidden subtitles.
        offAction.state = .on
        subtitlesLabel.isHidden = true
        
        /// set icon in transport bar menu.
        subtitlesMenu = UIMenu(title: Constants.Playback.productCardMenuTitle, image: captions, children: [submenu])
        #if os(tvOS)
        if let subtitlesMenu = subtitlesMenu {
            playerViewController.transportBarCustomMenuItems.append(subtitlesMenu)
        }
        #endif
    }
    

Also I want to remove the userdeafult data before killing the app.


First of all, it will be better to move this business logic to a separate class with a hardcoded key as a constant
class UserDefaultsManager {
    static let shared = UserDefaultsManager()

    private let captionStateKey = "captionState"

    func getCaptionState() -> UIMenuElement.State? {
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: captionStateKey) as? UIMenuElement.State
    }

    func setCaptionState(_ state: UIMenuElement.State) {
       UserDefaults.standard.set(state, forKey: captionStateKey)
    }

    // Method to clear specific UserDefaults keys
   func clearUserDefaults() {
      UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: captionStateKey)
  }
}


Forced downcasting is really dangerous (it can crash the app when there is no element). Try to use optional with default values
as! UIMenuElement.State


Like:
 let actionState = UserDefaultsManager.shared.getCaptionState() ?? .off


To clear UserDefault before killing the app, you should call an additional function from step on in the AppDelegate

 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
       // Clear UserDefaults data before the app is terminated
       UserDefaultsManager.shared.clearUserDefaults()
  }


